# C++, (GLUT) - maintaining a global vector of booleans in the display loop - crashes program

Tags: c++, opengl, button, vector, crash

I've got a bit of a tricky problem in my opinion. I'm new to C++ and OpenGL/ glut so be gentle!
I'm writing a platform-independent simple program (only 2D) and need a basic UI, so I have a Button class which generates a Button object. This hopefully will be able to be called dynamically (i think that's the right word) from inside the displayFunc() loop in OpenGL/ glut.

Every time the loop starts, it instantiates the correct button objects and then destroys them at the end. Of course, the buttons need to be able to do something, so in the glutMouseFunc function, it checks if the mouse clicked in the place needed to set off the button.

It is allowed access to the button member variables (xMin.. yMax) via get/set functions, which are public. However since the button is instantiated by the display loop, I had to create a global vector of pointers to the buttons which is updated as they are created, and cleaned up, along with the objects, at the end of the display loop. This is all fine and dandy I believe.

The tricky thing comes when I actually want a button to change state. The only thing I can come up with is having `std::vector<bool> buttonStates;`, which is augmented when the button is created, changed when the button is clicked, and destroyed when the button is.

Of course, this change of state doesn't carry through to the next loop of display, so I tried `std::vector<bool> btnStatesCopy;`, which maintains a copy of the buttonStates vector by using `btnStatesCopy = buttonStates;`when it changes, but is not destroyed at the end of the display loop. When the buttons are created, the button states now are copied from the btnStatesCopy vector, which has not changed since the last loop.

Unfortunately, this crashes my program, even when trying to print the btnStatesCopy vector. So I was wondering if you had any idea why it might crash, and what I might do to avoid it! I can post code, but I'm not sure it would help. Is there a better, more obvious way of doing this stuff that I haven't thought of? I would love to hear any ideas! Thanks a lot,
Patrick

Edit: Here's a concise version of the code if it help (keep in mind, I am really new at this stuff!):

```
//*in global scope*
// Stores pointers to the ui buttons.
std::vector<Button*> buttons;
// Stores button states, which are copied from buttonStates and
// destroyed every time display() runs.
std::vector<bool> buttonStates;
// Stores a copy of buttonstates which is written to when
// a button is pressed.
std::vector<bool> btnStatesCopy;

// Prototype functions:
void init(void);
void display(void);
void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void processHits(GLint hits, GLuint buffer[]);
void click(int button, int state, int x, int y);
void idle(void);
void resize(int width, int height);
void drawMenu(void);
void circle(float x,float y,float size,int segments);
void initialiseButtons();

// Main loop goes here; calls glutDisplayFunc(display);

void display(void) {
    initialiseButtons();
    drawMenu();
}

bool changeBinaryState(bool state){
    /* Changes 1 to 0 and 0 to 1. */
    if (state == 0) state = 1;
    else state = 0;
    return state;
}

void click(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
/* Called when a mouse button is clicked. */
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state != GLUT_DOWN) {
        std::cout<<x<<", "<<y<<std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i<buttons.size();i++){
            //put a pointer of a button in variable but
            Button* but = buttons.at(i);
            if (x > but->getMinX() && x < but->getMaxX()) {
                if (y > but->getMinY() && y < but->getMaxY()){
                    but->buttonFunc();
                    changeButtonState(buttonStates.at(i));
                    buttonStates.at(i) = 1;
                    btnStatesCopy = buttonStates;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void drawMenu(void) {
    // Create a button and its pointer and add pointer to buttons vector.
    Button* p_b = new InfoButton("User Manual",20,spacing+yOffset);
    buttons.push_back(p_b);
    // Add button state of previous button state.
    buttonStates.push_back(btnStatesCopy.back());

    // Turn on buttons if their state is on.
    for (unsigned i = 0; i<buttonStates.size();i++){
        if (buttonStates[i]==1) {
        Button* but = buttons.at(i);
        but->buttonFunc();
    }
}
void initialiseButtons(){
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < buttons.size();i++)
    {
        delete buttons[i];
    }
    buttons.clear();
    buttonStates.clear();
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code maybe? Also, why do you need ti create and destroy the button object? Why not just have a vector of those instead?

Comment: Yes I'll edit and add some code if you would like. The idea (just a fledgling in my mind) is to somehow take a string of the path from which the program was run, scan the path for .jpg files and create a button for each one with the filename. So since the buttons have to be created at run-time, I think they have to be created in the display loop (because otherwise they can't be seen!), which means being created and destroyed, as I see it.

Answer (score -1):

The title of your question reads

> Blockquote C++, (GLUT) - maintaining a global vector of ***pointers*** to booleans in the display loop - crashes program

(emphasis added). If I understand you correctly, that means you have

```
std::vector<bool*> buttonStates;
std::vector<bool*> btnStatesCopy;
```

and not `std::vector<bool>`.

If this is indeed the case, and if the bools which these pointers point to are deleted in the display loop, then they will be deleted in the display loop. You are retaining pointers to freed memory, and this is the most likely reason for a crash.

On the other hand, if this were Java (or any other garbage collected language) as opposed to C++, storing a pointer to an object protects it from being garbage collected.

Comment: No, sorry for not being clear, the state vectors themselves are just vectors of booleans as I wrote above; but there is also `std::vector<Button*> buttons;`, so it's a vector of pointers to my Button objects.

Comment: @PatrickReece If you access this ``vector`` outside or in the next iteration of the display loop, this would also crash. But to be honest, without seeing your code this is all pure speculation.

Comment: I've added my code in a way that hopefully makes sense (obviously there's more than that, I just truncated to the relevant bits). Do you still think accessing the vector in each iteration of the display loop would crash it?

Comment: Never mind, I though of a much better way of doing it. If you're interested, I have only one vector containing the pointers to buttons (instead of 3 vectors), and each button contains its own state as a private variable. 

The main difference was to instantiate the button out of the display loop, in init() so all the buttons are created when the window is created. I moved the display code for the button out of its constructor, and into a public function, which is called in the display loop! It works perfectly now, but thanks for the help!